# How to evaluate this anti-derivative?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to evaluate 
$$ \int \frac{1}{ \ln x} \ \mathrm{d} x, $$
where $\ln x$ denotes the natural logarithm of $x$?

My effort:

> We note that 
>   $$ \int \frac{1}{ \ln x} \ \mathrm{d} x = \int \frac{x}{x \ln x} \ \mathrm{d} x = \int x \frac{ \mathrm{d} }{ \mathrm{d} x } \left( \ln \ln x \right) \ \mathrm{d} x = x \ln \ln x - \int \ln \ln x \ \mathrm{d} x. $$

What next?

Another approach:

> We can also write 
>   $$ \int \frac{1}{ \ln x } \ \mathrm{d} x = \frac{x}{\ln x } + \int \frac{1}{ \left( \ln x \right)^2 } \ \mathrm{d} x = \frac{x}{\ln x } + \frac{x}{ \left( \ln x \right)^2 } + \int \frac{ 2 }{ \left( \ln x \right)^3 } \ \mathrm{d} x = \ldots = x \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \ln x \right)^{-k} + n \int \left( \ln x \right)^{-n-1} \ \mathrm{d} x. $$

What next?

Which one of the above two approaches, if any, is going to lead to a function consisting of finitely many terms comprised of elementary functions, that is, the kinds of solutions that we are used to in calculus courses?

Or, is there any other way that can lead us to a suitable enough answer?

Comment: If recollection serves, this is one of the standard examples of a function that does not have an antiderivative in terms of elementary functions. :\

Comment: See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function

Comment: $$\int_2^x \frac{dt}{\ln(t)} $$ is often called $Li(x)$

Comment: Why do you expect that this leads "to a function consisting of finitely many terms comprised of elementary functions, that is, the kinds of solutions that we are used to in calculus courses"?  Not all functions are of this type (although really digging into this involves [Liouville's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm)).

Comment: If You strong with `Limits` try: $\int \frac{1}{\log (x)} \, dx=-\underset{n\to 0^+}{\text{lim}}x \Phi \left(x^n,1,\frac{1}{n}\right)+C$ where: $ \Phi$ is  Lerch transcendent function.

Answer (score 1):

I = $\large\int\frac{1}{ln(x)}dx$

let ln(x) =  u

$\,e^u = x$

$\,dx = e^udu$

I = $\,\int \frac{e^u}{u}du$

expanding e$^u$,

I=$\,\int\frac{1+u+\frac{u^2}{2!}+\frac{u^3}{3!}+\frac{u^4}{4!}+\frac{u^5}{5!}..............}{u}du$

I = $\,\int\frac{1}{u}+1+\frac{u}{2!}+\frac{u^2}{3!}+\frac{u^3}{4!}+\frac{u^4}{5!}...........du$

I = $\,ln(u)+ u + \frac{u^2}{2.2!}+\frac{u^3}{3.3!}+\frac{u^4}{4.4!}+\frac{u^5}{5.5!}......+ C$

I = $\,ln(ln(x)) + ln(x) + \frac{(ln(x))^2}{2.2!} + \frac{(ln(x))^3}{3.3!} + \frac{(ln(x))^4}{4.4!} + \frac{(ln(x))^5}{5.5!} + ....... + C $

I = $\,ln(ln(x)) + ln(x) + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(ln(x))^k}{k.k!} + C $

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be expressed with the *elementary functions*. Actually, it is a *special function*, the *integral logarithm*:
$$\operatorname{li}(x)=\int_0^x\frac{\mathrm dt}{\ln t}\biggl(=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_0^{1-\varepsilon}\frac{\mathrm dt}{\ln t}+\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{1+\varepsilon}^\infty\frac{\mathrm dt}{\ln t}\quad\text{for }x>1\biggr)$$
and  it is asymptotically equivalent to $\;\dfrac x{\ln x}$.

Closely linked is the function $$\operatorname{Li}(x)=\int_2^x\frac{\mathrm dt}{\ln t}=\operatorname{li}(x)-\operatorname{li}(2), $$
 used in number theory: it is a asymptotic equivalent of $\pi(x)$, the number of primes $\le x$.